# Progress Bar Android

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to create progressBar when the app is first create and then move to the second activity but im stuck here can somebody help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();


    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                    mProgressStatus ++;
                    // Update the progress bar
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private void startPlaces() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Second Class :

```
public class Places extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your xml code for progressbar and make sure mProgress is visible

Comment: Hello thank you for answer here my xml code for progressbar     <ProgressBar
        style="@style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

Comment: just replace your ProgressBar  as I shown in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for circular progress bar you can try this
http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/creating-circular-progressbar-in-android.html

and for starting the another activity as soon as done with the progress bar
outside the while loop you can call

mProgress.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   startPlaces();

                }

            });
```

Comment: Hi i need to move the first activity after about 3 second to the second activity  when the progressbar is  done spinning

Comment: for three second you can add sleep(30) inside while loop

Comment: try {
                               Thread.sleep(30);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }